# $(document).ready(function(){} jquery is getting called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to jquery..I have written a jquery function to process some form inputs. I see an strange issue that my   `$(document).ready(function(){}` is getting called twice.

My form is;

```
<form>
...........
       <div class="form-actions" id="saveButtons"> 
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" /><%=i18n.localize("save")%></button>
                    <%if(outputs.isPermitted){%><script> </script><a class="btn btn-info" id="publish_api" >Save & Publish</a>  <%}%>
                    <input type="reset" class="btn" value="<%=i18n.localize("cancel")%>" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='./'" />                                         
                </div>
            </form>
```

And the jquery is;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


    $('#publish_api').click(function(e){
        $("body").on("api_saved", function(e){
            $.ajax({
                ........
        });
        $("#manage_form").submit();
    });

</script>
```

I see above alert twice when i click `save and publish` button. This issue occurs if there any user error in filling the form. (That is, if user does not fill a MUST field and agin if he filled that entry and try to click the button) What would be the cause?

**Edit;**
The "api-saved" event handler is called from a javascript like; (to validate all params in that form)

```
var v = $("#manage_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        if(!validate_tiers()){
            return false;
        }

        $('#saveMessage').show();
        $('#saveButtons').hide();        
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success:function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                $('#saveMessage').hide();
                $('#saveButtons').show();                
                if (!responseText.error) {                
                    $( "body" ).trigger( "api_saved" );       
                } else {
.........

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nesting event handler assignment, which is *usually* a bug.  You've got:

```
$('#publish_api').click(function(e){
```

which establishes a handler for the "click" event from an element.  Inside that event handler is code that sets up *another* event handler:

```
    $("body").on("api_saved", function(e){
        alert("calling lifecycle jag");
        // ...
```

The reason that's likely to be a bug is that every call to `.on()` inside the "click" handler will attach a separate copy of that event handler. After clicking twice, there will be two identical handlers for the "api_saved" event. After clicking 5 times, there'll be 5 handlers, and so on. That happens because a call to `.on()` does *not* remove event handlers that are already registered.

Probably the right thing to do is move that event handler assignment (the one for "api_saved") out of the "click" handler.

Comment: You are right.. I clicked more than two times and my document.ready() is getting called that many times. Can you point me a code sample to correct this?

Comment: If i move that out , how can i handle button click function and submit the form?

Comment: @Ratha I don't know what you mean; it is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. What generates that "api_saved" event?

Comment: It passes some data to backend and get results ..( Here this JS is kind of server side script) i edit my original question with  more code in the api-saved event handler.

Comment: Well the code `$("body").on("api_saved", ...` establishes an event handler for an event called "api_saved".  I don't see anything in your code that *generates* an event like that (which would probably be a call like `$("body").trigger("api_saved");`.

Comment: @Ratha Sorry, but I still don't understand. Why do you need the "api_saved" handler at all? Can't you perform the `$.ajax()` call directly from the "click" handler?

Comment: Well, nowhere on that page is there any code to trigger an event called "api_saved". (If there is, I can't find it, but it'd be helpful if you added that to the question.)  If nothing triggers that event, then the code in the event handler will not be called. Thus I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: I have edited my que, where i explained why i call api-saved event handler