# How to solve this in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form where I validate the user's input and when they click a button the form is submitted.

My sample code:

**Form :**

```
<form>
...

   <div class="form-actions" id="saveButtons"> 
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" /><%=i18n.localize("save")%></button>
                    <%if(outputs.isPermitted){%><script> </script><a class="btn btn-info" id="publish_api" >Save & Publish</a>  <%}%>

                </div>
            </form>
```

**When click button i call this jquery function:**

```
    $('#publish_api').click(function(e){
                $("body").on("api_saved", function(e){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<%=site.context%>/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag",
                        data: {
                            action :"updateStatus",
...

   });
            $("#manage_form").submit();
        });

And form  input parameter validation happens in another js function:



var v = $("#manage_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        if(!validate_tiers()){
            return false;
        }


        $('#saveMessage').show();
        $('#saveButtons').hide();        
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success:function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                $('#saveMessage').hide();
                $('#saveButtons').show();                
                if (!responseText.error) {                
                    $( "body" ).trigger( "api_saved" );       
                } else {
...
```

Now my issue is, since I have registered **.on()** handler within the **click()** event, if the user clicks the button without filling in the mandatory fields the data is still sent to the backend after he correctly fills out the form and clicks submit.

This occurs because I have registered the `.on` event handler within the `click()` function.
How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Your issue is a bit unclear...

Comment: It sounds like you need to validate, THEN submit.  Your validation should be run on click, then if everything passes, submit the information

Comment: @RobertRozas i asked similar question here, based on that i would like to solve above issue..i think my logic is right but quite not sure, what is the right event handler i should use instead of .on() handler.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958631/document-readyfunction-jquery-is-getting-called-twice/26958707#26958707

Comment: @ratha Your `.on()` is just a binding event that allows you use whatever event you want.  Either `.on('click', function(){...})` or `.click(function(){...})` is normally the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understand your issue correctly yo can overcome it simply by binding the `.on()`-handler **outside** the `.click()`-handler:

```
// this submits the form when button is clicked
$('#publish_api').click(function(e){$("#manage_form").submit();});

// and this makes the ajax-call when "api_saved"-event is triggered
$("body").on("api_saved", function(e){ /* ... */ });
```

But I'm not shure this beeing the only issue.